# R write_ods function send back status 127

Tags: r, ods

I try to write `ods` file using `R`, with the `readODS` package. It is working fine on a computer, on another, with the same code, I get :

```
Warning message:
running command '"zip" -r9X "test.ods" "content.xml" "META-INF" "meta.xml" "mimetype" "styles.xml" ' had status 127
```

My code is :

```
library(readODS)
write_ods(cars,path)
```

What should I do ? I figure I have to install a `zip` command, but what is this ?

Comment: Visiblement, il n'y a que deux Insee qui ont rencontré le même problème : amusant. Ma réponse est ci-dessous.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with the `readODS::write_ods()` function.
It came from the fact that `zip` command was not recognized on my system.
First of all, here is my `sessionInfo()`:

> R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

I solved this error installing `Rtools` on my computer: check if `Rtools` is installed. If not, you can download it here : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
In my case, `Rtools` is installed in `C:\RBuildTools\3.4\`. In this directory, one can find a `bin` subdirectory with `zip.exe` inside. Finally, I added `C:\RBuildTools\3.4\bin\` to the `PATH` environment variable, and `readODS::write_ods()` works fine !

I hope that it will help you.